# Import from Intergraph G/Technology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, dxf, intergraph

we currently use Hexagon's Intergraph G/Technology. Unfortunately, when exporting (via dwg / dxf) and importing into QGIS, all symbols (e.g. hydrants) are displayed in the wrong place. The symbols are displayed using special fonts. The display is correct in Autocad or other viewers. Has anyone here already gained experience? Unfortunately, the shifting of the symbols is not always the same.

Comment: Please upload an example file.

Comment: https://c.web.de/@722373261286970467/Jbgt3gKSQV-ChbwsIPDvtQ

Please excuse the late reply.

Comment: A password is required for your zip archive :-(

Comment: Please download again. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AnotherDXF2Shape should have solved the problem in its current version V1.3.0

AnotherDXF2Shape (QGIS):
[image]

AutoCAD
[image]

A notice:
Only the font 'GNet-Wasser-Symbolik-1.ttf' was installed

Comment: That looks very good, but the corners of the building (ALKIS Symbolik 11.ttf) are now shifted. Maybe you can fix that too.

Comment: AnotherDXFImporter "V1.3.1" should have solved the problem

Comment: AnotherDXFImporter "V1.3.1" solved the problem. Thanks alot.